# Add a scroll bar with minimum and maximum dates flot chart

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a flot chart that is using the navigation plug in and arrows to pan - 100px in the direction they want to go.  What I want to be able to do is change the clicking of arrows to a scroll bar which can be set as the min and max dates of the graph.

Is this possible to control this chart via a scroll bar?  This is the current code performed on a click:

```
 .click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
plotLines.pan(offset); 
 });
```

Where offset will be either +100 or -100px.  It would be nice if the date range appeared on what was visible in that window on the graph but that is not possible.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a scroll bar to the flot graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117279/how-to-add-a-scroll-bar-to-the-flot-graph)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a public implementation, but [this forum question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/flot-graphs/scroll/flot-graphs/JOGLwT-t_pw) asked the same thing.

My suggestion in that post was to create the plot as normal, then add a div beneath it that is the same width as the plot, and just tall enough to hold a scroll bar.  You would set its overflow-x to 'scroll' and overflow-y to 'hidden'.  Within that div you would place another div with a width corresponding to the overall width of your data, i.e. larger than the size of the placeholder.

You'll then be able to listen for scroll events and update the plot according to the position of the bar.