# How to add a scroll bar to X-axis or Y-axis in canvas using flot graph

Tags: javascript, flot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8fiZ.jpg]
I have a multi-series flot graph which is plotted in a canvas of width and height. When the flot graph has multi series it tries to compress within the height and width of  the canvas and the flot graph wont't be seen clearly.

In order to obtain a clear graph with all the series visible with all the nodes I want to  introduce a scroll bar in such a way that the scroll bar fits only few series at first  then by scrolling the rest of the series should be seen .

How do i do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the [panning and zooming](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/navigate/index.html) plugin (as @MF82 suggests) and want a true scroll bar, just wrap the container target div in another div:

```
<div 
  style="width:315px;height:300px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <div class="chart" id="placeholder1" style="width:300px;height:1000px;">
     </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/94SDd/).

```js
$(function () {
    
    var plot1 = $.plot($("#placeholder1"),[ 
        { data: [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]], label: "Series A"}
    ], {
        series: {
            lines: { show: true },
            points: { show: true }
        },
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: [[0,"One"],[1,"Two"],[2,"Three"]]
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/javascript/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<div 
  style="width:315px;height:300px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <div class="chart" id="placeholder1" style="width:300px;height:1000px;">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did the same way but its not scrolling instead its compressing the series of the graph inside the canvas

Comment: @Vidya, edit your question to show the code you are using or better yet create a jsFiddle that duplicates with "compression".

Comment: sir i wrapped it in a division its working fine :) But 1 problem I am facing is if there is only one series in the graph it still puts up a scroll bar and shows it somewhere in the middle of placeholder. So to see that particular series I need to scroll but I dont want that to happen. how can i do it sir?

Comment: @Vidya, please create an example jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a div:

```
<div class="graph">
   <!-- here the graph -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .graph
 {
 width: 200px;
 overflow-y:scroll; 
 overflow-x:hidden;
 }
```

WIth the overflow attribute, you can control where a scrollbar should be.

Comment: I did the same way but its not adding a scroll to the canvas. Instead adding to a div which is of no use. Only if window size overflows then it adds scroll. But i need to add scroll to the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass some options to Flot (with Navigation plugin), such as:

```
pan: {
    interactive: true
},
xaxis: {
    panRange: [Your xmin, your xmax]
}
```

where panRange means:

> "panRange" confines the panning to stay within a range, e.g. with
>   panRange: [-10, 20] panning stops at -10 in one end and at 20 in the
>   other. Either can be null.

[Navigation example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/navigate/index.html)