# Add scroll bar to the constructCanvas function in jquery.flot.js

Tags: javascript, flot

I need to add a scroll bar to the canvas of the flot graph wherein if the canvas overflows it should show a scroll bar. How do i do it?

Comment: Duplicate perhaps? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117279/how-to-add-a-scroll-bar-to-the-flot-graph

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
<div id="outercontainer" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; overflow: scroll;">
    <div id="innercontainer" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

and plot the chart in the inner container.